# Why is my output not being stored in the file C++

Tags: c++, file, authentication, store, login-system

I am writing a login system, I made a registration function that takes a username and password and checks both for exceptions, and then if they are correct it stores it into a file, but it doesn't store it into the file.

```
void reg(){
    fin.open("records.txt",ios::in);
    fout.open("records.txt", ios::app | ios::out);
    if(fout.is_open()){
        string temp_u;
        string temp_p;
        bool loop=true;
        do{
            bool invalid=false;
            bool same_id=false;
            cout<<"Enter Username:"<<endl;
            getline(cin>>ws,temp_u);
            cout<<"Enter Password:"<<endl;
            cin>>temp_p;
                
            try{
                int i=0,number=0;
                while(temp_p[i]!='\0'){
                if(temp_p[i]>='0'&&temp_p[i]<='9'){
                    number++;
                }
                i++;
                } 
                    
                if(number<=3){
                    string mess="Password must have atleast 3 digits!:\n";
                    throw mess;
                }
            }
            catch(string mess){
                system("cls");
                cout<<mess<<endl;
                invalid=true;
            }
            try{
                string mess;
                while(fin>>user>>pass){
                    if(temp_u==user){
                        cout<<"checking"<<endl;
                        mess="ID already exists choose another one\n";
                        throw mess; 
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(string mess){
                system("cls");
                cout<<mess<<endl;
                same_id=true;
            }
            if(invalid==false && same_id==false){
                loop=false;
                fout<<temp_u<<"\t\t"<<temp_p<<"\n";
            }
                
            }while(loop==true);
        }
        
        fout.close();
        fin.close();}
```

So I have declared an if statement that, when the password will be acceptable and when the user id will not be similar to the old ones, the bool variable which runs the loop will be false and the user id and password will be stored in the file.

```
int main(){ 
    login l;
     l.reg();
    return 0;}
```

Comment: What does "it doesn't store it into the file" mean? What is this program's current directory when it gets executed. What are the contents of that directory. Please document this additional information. Can you follow Stackoverflow's instructions for creating a [mre], that everyone else can cut/paste, ***exactly as shown***, then compile, run, and reproduce your problem themselves. See [ask] in the [help] for more information.

Comment: Sorry for not sharing that much, my program doesn't have that much this is most of it my program is taking just 2 inputs username and password, and only stores the id and password in a text file.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but the way the code uses `try` and `catch` is unusual and not recommended. Exceptions are for problems that can't be handled locally. The code here handles the errors directly, so there is no need for exceptions. Just copy the code from the `catch` clauses into the corresponding `try` clause in place of the `throw`.

Comment: I know I do not have to use catch or even try in this matter, I am preparing for my exam, therefore, using most of the concepts taught in this system, hence the unusual implementations.

Comment: Well, unless you share a [mre], as explained in Stackoverflow's [help], it is unlikely that anyone will be able to help you. See [ask] for more information.

Comment: @Qartzai -- if you're supposed to write that kind of stuff for your exam you're being taught badly. You have my sympathy.

Comment: @Qartzai Do not open the same file twice simultaneously. Open the file for reading, read what you want from it, then close the file and open it again for writing. Write what you want and then close it again.